# w3wp Memory Dump .NET Usage Size Disparity

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, dotmemory

We are currently investigating a memory leak in our ASP.NET API application but we are seeing some strange results when we analyse memory dumps.

We are obtaining the dumps by remoting onto the box during testing and identifying the w3wp process that is using the most memory (we have multiple app pools on the box so there are multiple w3wp processes but one of them is using significantly more than the others) then using Task Manage to create a dump file.

Typically the dump files are over 1GB but when we analyse them using dotMemory it says the total object space is ten's of MBs.

Obviously the whole dump isn't going to be .NET memory usage but that seems like a big disparity. Could this caused by how we are taking the dumps? What else could be using the memory?

Comment: probably you already know, but if you work with Streams (memory, files, IO), make sure you always dispose them. File streams can occupy a lot of memory if not disposed. Also, if you work if database (directly or you use an ORM such as Entity Framework), mare sure you always dispose the connection.

Comment: While you are hosting an ASP.NET 4.x web app on IIS, the actual memory usage can be determined by many factors, even unmanaged modules can take up spaces which dotMemory might not be able to help analyze. Try to open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com if you want some help.

Comment: I suggest you open a [support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com) for this, microsoft engineers will help analyse the dump file and  try to find the root cause.